# Access global vue variable from vuex store module

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I hope someone can point me in the right direction here.
In my Vue.js application, I have defined a global variable $test in my main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { store } from '../src/store/store';


Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.prototype.$store = store;

Vue.prototype.$test = 'Testing';

new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

How do I access this variable from a Vuex store module? I've tried `this.$test` and other combinations with no luck.

This is from the vuex store module (shortened for this example). This module is imported to my store.ts as a separate module.

```
export default {
    state: {
        .....
    },
    mutations: {
        ......
    },
    actions: {
        testMyVar(context: any) {
            console.log(this.$test); //What am I doing wrong here???
        }
    },
    getters: {
        ....
    }
}
```

**Edit**: basically what I want to do is to mock a library and initiate it from my index.html on my local dev station. Then make the initiated class available from my store modules.

In production the class is already initiated and the variable just needs to be accessible from my vuex store modules.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just add the variable to the vuex state and call it whenever you need it?

Comment: Thanks for the input. That was the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
state: {
    .....
},
mutations: {
    ......
},
actions: {
    testMyVar(context: any) {
        console.log(Vue.prototype.$test); //just import vue in store
    }
},
getters: {
    ....
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following: this.$store.state.varName

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).